# making a usb device a different joystick

Tags: udev

searching web and found "lsusb: to list my devices I get:
bus001 004 id32be:1402

I am using this usb device (flight yoke) in an arcade cab running Linux (Arpicade) that MUST use js0 js1 js2 js3. What happens is when flight yoke is plugged in js1 becomes js3 and js2 becomes js4, the flight yoke is seen as js0.  If I unplug flight yoke and reboot, everything returns to normal and works.

How or what do I need to do to force this flight yoke to the back of the line so to speak? I am completely green and know nothing of Linux. I was told maybe a udev rule?

This AM I managed to figure out device IDs:

Joystick: Start initialization
Input: Adding joystick #0: BaolianindustryCo.,Ltd.BLflightyoke#1 (device id: 03000000be3200000214000011010000)
Joystick: Baolian industry Co., Ltd. BL flight yoke #1 [GUID 03000000be3200000214000011010000]
Joystick:   ...  2 axes, 15 buttons 0 hats 0 balls
Joystick:   ...  Physical id 0 mapped to logical id 1
Joystick:   ...  Does not have haptic capability

Input: Adding joystick #1: XboxGamepad(userspacedriver) (device id: 0000000058626f782047616d65706100)
Joystick: Xbox Gamepad (userspace driver) [GUID 0000000058626f782047616d65706100]
Joystick:   ...  4 axes, 15 buttons 0 hats 0 balls
Joystick:   ...  Physical id 1 mapped to logical id 2
Joystick:   ...  Does not have haptic capability

Input: Adding joystick #2: GPIOController1 (device id: 15000000010000000100000000010000)
Joystick: GPIO Controller 1 [GUID 15000000010000000100000000010000]
Joystick:   ...  2 axes, 9 buttons 0 hats 0 balls
Joystick:   ...  Physical id 2 mapped to logical id 3
Joystick:   ...  Does not have haptic capability

Input: Adding joystick #3: GPIOController2 (device id: 15000000010000000200000000010000)
Joystick: GPIO Controller 2 [GUID 15000000010000000200000000010000]
Joystick:   ...  2 axes, 9 buttons 0 hats 0 balls
Joystick:   ...  Physical id 3 mapped to logical id 4
Joystick:   ...  Does not have haptic capability
Joystick: End initialization

I need to get the Baolian flight yoke off js0 and put at js4 (or js3 Im not sure)

Comment: The number should not matter check the permissions of the device I use a flight controller and had to setup a udev rules to change the permissions when the controller was plugged in something like this.  `ATTRS{idVendor}=="0483", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5750", MODE="0666"`  You would have to change the numbers obviously to match your vendor and product.  When everything is working check what the permissions on the `js?` are.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. But I'm clueless on Linux. The developer of the software told me  I need to make a udev rule or ??? somehow get the flight yoke to be seen as js4 because he has js0 js1 js2 js3 already in use (ones a virtual js). For some reason it's working when the flight yoke isn't plugged in but as mentioned somehow is being seen as the first joystick which then pushes the other order off. He doesn't have a flight stick to help figure it out so I'm on this quest to figure it out.